# background-size: cover not vertically aligned only in desktop Safari

Tags: css, safari, background-size

I have a background image on the body of my page that should be centered vertical and horizontally and covering the canvas.

```
  body {
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(background_phone_2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

In Chrome/Firefox and all mobile browsers, the image is centered both vertically and horizontally and covering the canvas. In Safari on desktop, the image is slightly below vertical center. Am I doing something wrong or could this possibly a browser bug?

The live url of this is: http://moonios.com

I've tried removing the overflow: none as well as removing the other contents of the page, but the issue persists.

If you have any advice or can confirm this bug, I'd appreciate it. Thank you! Charlie

Update: Did a little more work into figuring this out. Built this new page with a grid: http://whyamicrazytoday.com/safari/

The entire page contents are:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Safari Background Size Bug</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url(background.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still reproduces only in Safari.

[image: Safari vs Chrome]

Then I remembered the translucency effect in Safari's nav bar (although I have it turned off). I believe Safari is considering the body area to cover that top nav bar which throws off my vertical centering since the content of the page does not get considered in that way. Is there a way to disable that effect from the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to do a browser hack and targeting Safari with special CSS to fix this, I checked in El Capitan and this behavior is corrected. So I'm going to abandon this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with only these properties;

```
background-image: url(background_phone_2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

That should work.

If not, why not make a `div` with the image and use `z-index` to make it the background? This would be much easier to center than a background image on the body.

Other than that try:

`background-position: 0 100px;/*use a pixel value that will center it*/` Or I think you can use 50% if you have set your body `min-height` to 100%.

```
body{

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image:url(background_phone_2.jpg);
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that all a go, but it seems like it actually might be a Safari issue with translucency. Check out my update in the main post.